# Importing module from Python non standard library

Tags: python, import, module, banking

I am a beginner here. I am trying to use a bank simulator module in Python, whose name is banksim, but I do not get to do so. If I write the code `import banksim`, an error is returned. Furthermore, there is no `pip install` mentioned by the developer of the aforementioned module. Could anyone please help me to solve this issue? Thanks indeed!

The module is in:
https://github.com/banking-project/banksim

How can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just clone the repository or download it as a zip and extract it. Just copy the `banksim` folder into the root folder of your project you want to use the module in and import it from there.

Also run `pip install -r requirements.txt` for the `requirements.txt` in the repository.

Answer (score 2):

Create a text file called `requirements.txt` inside the folder that contains the `pip.exe`.

The content of the file should be:

```
mesa==0.8.5
#dash==0.38.0  # The core dash backend
#dash-html-components==0.13.5  # HTML components
#dash-core-components==0.43.1  # Supercharged components
#dash-table==3.5.0  # Interactive DataTable component (new!)
#dash-daq==0.1.0  # DAQ components (newly open-sourced!)
```

Then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` in your command prompt.